# AWS S3 ERROR useFipsEndpoint: options.useFipsEndpoint ?? false,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTdUd.png)

I got this

```
useFipsEndpoint: options.useFipsEndpoint ?? false,
                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
```

Error while doing aws s3.
my current node version is 18.18 and

```
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.478.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.478.0",
```

aws sdk versions are like this.

i tried it with upgrading to new versions.i also tried it with node version 20 also. the error still exist.but this same functionality is running in my another project with same version and code implementation also same smoothly.have anyone experienced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the image you share, this error is probably related to the Node version you are using.
The Nullish coalescing operator (`??`) [was introduced in Node 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing#browser_compatibility).

I was experiencing the same error when running my project through VSCode Debug.
In my case it ran the debugger with Node 12 which is the default node version in my NVM (run `nvm list` and check what version the alias `default` points to)

You can check your node version via `node -v` or via `nvm current`

You can also enforce the node version via debugger configuration using the `runtimeVersion` option (requires `nvm`):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node",
            "runtimeVersion": "20"
        }
    ]
}
```